Handling of Column Overflow in MySQL: Identification and Differentiation
In MySQL, if a row record is too large, some columns may overflow in order to fulfill the rule that at least two records are stored in a page.
For example, consider the table t:
create table t(c1 varchar(10000) not null) row_format compact;

I insert a row into the table:
insert into t values(repeat('a', 10000));

According to MySQL's default settings, the column c1 will overflow at this point. MySQL uses a page to store the first 768 bytes of this field plus 20 bytes to record some overflow page information.
My question is, does the record format in MySQL have a flag indicating that the c1 column has overflowed, and that these 788 bytes need to be interpreted as having uncompressed data? If no such indicator exists, how does MySQL determine that a column has overflowed? After all, even if a page hasn't overflowed, this field might just happen to be 788 bytes long. For example, inserting the following data should not cause an overflow:
insert into t values(repeat('a', 788));

How does MySQL differentiate these two scenarios?

There's no way to query a given record to find out if a column or columns have overflowed.
You could use Jeremy Cole's InnoDB scripts to examine the internal storage of individual pages, but it'd take some work to locate the page for a given record.
By the way, you're mixing up a few details about InnoDB record storage. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/innodb-row-format.html
In COMPACT row format, a long string stores the string's first 768 bytes, then the remainder on overflow page(s), referenced by a 20-byte pointer.
In DYNAMIC or COMPRESSED row formats, long strings are not split between the primary page and the overflow pages. A string is either stored completely on the primary page if they are up to 788 bytes, or else completely on overflow page(s), and the primary page only stores the 20-byte pointer to the overflow pages.
In neither case is there any way in SQL to query how a given record is stored. This is internal to the storage engine, not surface through the API.
The closest thing I found was to query information_schema.innodb_metrics which allows you to check if there was any overflow page updated. But it doesn't tell you for which record, or even which transaction did the update to an overflow page.

I'm not concerned about whether MySQL exposes related data or methods; I just want to understand the internal implementation details of MySQL.

I think this is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. The implementation details are all in the code: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/trunk/storage/innobase/data/data0data.cc#L422
